# 'Zend_Session_Exception Error in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a website in zend framework which is install in another server. Now I have purchase a new server in ubuntu with Zend Engine 2.3.0 . I have installed Apache server, MYSQL , PHPMYADMIN Tool on this server. Then I upload all the files on previous server to the new server. I have also change the urls in the index.php files.

But it is giving me error.
****Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /var/www/sample/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:477):Error #2 session_start(): open(/vlk_session/sess_ielitiholu4219p3nph6lkk8n6, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) /var/www/videoliked/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:487): ****

This is my below code of index.php file

```
    Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);

Zend_Session::setOptions(array('save_path'=>'/vlk_session'));
if(isset($_COOKIE["Zend_Auth_RememberMe"]) && $_COOKIE["Zend_Auth_RememberMe"] !== false){
    Zend_Session::rememberMe("5302000");
    setcookie("Zend_Auth_RememberMe", false, time(), "/");
}



if(!Zend_Session::isStarted()){

    Zend_Session::start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The save path is absolute.

Did you create the folder `/vlk_session` on your server?

I'd suggest to use and create

```
/tmp/vlk_session
```

Instead, or lookup the PHP default folder for sessions in your `php.ini` and use the one suggested by vendor.

Update:

Make sure the PHP instance is allowed to read/write that folder.